# 302 in magento rest api call on shared hosting

Tags: magento-1.9, api

In magento 1.9.1 .0 I have made a few REST APIs and they work very well in my local machine. But When I moved the code to hosting environment, it is giving me 302 status code. I supposed the api itself is not working but while debugging I found that api functions well but in browser I get 302. A Similar question is here  [302 Moved Temporarily](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101810/302-found-in-rest-request-using-post-method).  Googled much but nothing helped me!

How can I get it working? I welcome all constructive suggestions.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

By 302 that means you get redirected. You need to play around with your restapi url. For example your default rest api url looks like these:
http://magentohost/api/rest/

But your hosting for example has a redirect to www, then your link should looks like that
http://www.magentohost/api/rest/

Maybe you site using https then the correct link will be something like 
   https://magentohost/api/rest/

Or maybe your hosting used index.php for the controller generated links? Then the correct link to your rest api should be
http://magentohost/index.php/api/rest/

Just play around with your rest api url and you should be fine with the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! @electroid. Surely I check the urls of api. By the way, when I used echos and exits in the api file it echoed the values correctly and I got it working. But it didn't work when I run usually. So eventually I placed an exit(0) at the end of the api, next to the actual echo statement which throws back some data. And it worked well. is this a good practice?

Comment: @velavasimmanarumugan, place your code, please.

Comment: sorry but which code exactly, the api POST call or actual api code?

Comment: @velavasimmanarumugan, your rest api call please.